# How does calling a function within a function work in this snippet of python code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to parse a json input that is basically a dictionary within a dictionary. From suggestions and input from others, this seems to work but I have no idea how I can troubleshoot it to understand it better.

I tried returning myprint, but it doesn't really show me how it is iterating through the nested dictionary.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

def myprint(d, apistring, url):
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            **myprint(v, apistring, url)**
        else:
           if apistring in v:
              print("{0}{1}".format(url, v))

def main():
    apistring = "/api/"
    url = "https://example.com"


    input_text = {"country": {"china": "/api/v1/china/", "canada": "/api/v1/china/canada/"}, "continent": {"asia": "/api/v1/asia/", "africa": "/api/v1/asia/africa/"}, "islands": {"madagascar": "/api/v1/madagascar/", "palau": "/api/v1/madagascar/palau/"}}

    myprint(input_text, apistring, url)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

- https://example.com/api/v1/china/
- https://example.com/api/v1/china/canada/
- https://example.com/api/v1/asia/
- https://example.com/api/v1/asia/africa/
- https://example.com/api/v1/madagascar/
- https://example.com/api/v1/madagascar/palau/

Comment: You should read about [how recursion works in Python](https://thepythonguru.com/python-recursive-functions/).

Comment: Or read the Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science) Recursion is a general programming technique, not specific to Python.